# XBee AT communication between PC and Arduino

Tags: arduino, xbee

I need to send data (an integer) from an Arduino to a C program on a PC. I know that the connection is fine, because with X-CTU works perfectly. I need to do this in AT mode but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Have you tried [libxbee](https://code.google.com/p/libxbee/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the XBee modules in AT mode, then it isn't much different than what you'd have to do with a direct serial cable connection between the Arduino and PC.  Look for sample programs demonstrating serial communications for both platforms.

Having the connection working with X-CTU is an excellent starting point, since you have confirmed that the radio modules are communicating correctly.

On the PC, you might want to look at this Open Source [XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) on GitHub.  It includes a sample program called "xbee_term" that demonstrates a simple serial terminal for using an XBee in AT mode.  It also has a layered API to allow for easy use of XBee modules in API mode -- which you would need to use if the PC was going to communicate with multiple Arduino nodes running in AT mode.

As for sending an `int`, you can use `sprintf()` to format it as a string to send over the wireless link, and `strtol()` to convert it back to an `int` on the PC end.